# Bitnami mongodb helm chart custom username and password is not working

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I have deployed mongodb using Bitnami mongodb helm chart. I am using values.yaml file like this.

```
mongodb: 
  auth:
    enabled: true 
    rootUser: root
    rootPassword: password123
    usernames: ["testuser"]
    passwords: ["testuser_password"]
    databases: ["testdb"]
```

When I exec into the mongodb pod, I am using the below command and able to authenticate with the **admin** db using username **root** and rootpassword .

```
mongosh admin --host "test-mongodb" --authenticationDatabase admin -u $MONGODB_ROOT_USER -p $MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

But if I want to login to **testdb** with the **username** and **password** (not admin username and password) I am getting *Authentication failure*.

```
mongosh admin --host "test-mongodb" --authenticationDatabase testdb -u testuser -p testuser_password
```

So the question is- am I setting-up/passing the *username*,*password* and *db* names correctly? or Do I need to create users and password as part of the initdbscripts in the values.yaml?

Can something help with this , please?

Comment: Did you ever able to fix this issue?